# Air for iOS - Unexpected or unknown element or attribute in the application

Tags: ios, xml, air

I am attempting to package an ipa file and am getting the following error:

[Error creating files.
Unexpected or unknown element or attribute in the application descriptor file.
application.iPhone is an unexpected element/attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkH7i.png)

My development environment: Win10, Flash CC 2015, Air 19.0.0.241. I am also using the Push notifications ANE from Milkman games. I am using a production certificate and provisioning profile. Ultimately I want to test the app on iOS in TestFlight.

I had some suggestions from other developers but none have presented any  viable solutions. The issues seems to be in either the iPhone or entitlements tag.

I also went through the [Air Applications Descriptor Elements Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html) but I have figured anything out yet.

Taken from the air application descriptor docs for the iPhone tag:
iPhone
Defines iOS-specific application properties.
Parent element:application
Child elements:
    Entitlements
    externalSwfs
    forceCPURenderModeForDevices
    InfoAdditions
    requestedDisplayResolution

Can anyone help me with this? Here is he code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?>

<!--

    Usage:

    To localize the description, use the following format for the description element.

    <description>
    <text xml:lang="en">English App description goes here</text>
    <text xml:lang="fr">French App description goes here</text>
    <text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App description goes here</text>
    </description>

     To localize the name, use the following format for the name element.

    <name>
   <text xml:lang="en">English App name goes here</text>
   <text xml:lang="fr">French App name goes here</text>
   <text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App name goes here</text>
    </name>

-->

<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/19.0">
  <id>com.myapp.app</id>
  <versionNumber>1.2.1</versionNumber>
  <filename>MyAppName</filename>
  <description/>

  <name>MyAppName</name>

  <initialWindow>
    <content>MyApp.swf</content>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
    <renderMode>direct</renderMode>
    <autoOrients>true</autoOrients></initialWindow>

  <icon>

    <image29x29>Icons/ah_29.png</image29x29>
   <image57x57>Icons/ah_57.png</image57x57>
   <image114x114>Icons/ah_114.png</image114x114>
    <image512x512>Icons/ah_512.png</image512x512>
    <image48x48>Icons/ah_48.png</image48x48>
    <image72x72>Icons/ah_72.png</image72x72>
    <image50x50>Icons/ah_50.png</image50x50>
    <image58x58>Icons/ah_58.png</image58x58>
    <image100x100>Icons/ah_100.png</image100x100>
    <image144x144>Icons/ah_144.png</image144x144>
    <image1024x1024>Icons/ah_1024.png</image1024x1024>
    <image40x40>Icons/ah_40.png</image40x40>
    <image76x76>Icons/ah_76.png</image76x76>
    <image80x80>Icons/ah_80.png</image80x80>
    <image120x120>Icons/ah_120.png</image120x120>
    <image152x152>Icons/ah_152.png</image152x152>

  </icon>
  <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
  <allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>
   <supportedLanguages>en</supportedLanguages>


  <iPhone>
    <Entitlements>
<![CDATA[
<key>application-identifier</key>
<string>000000000.com.myapp.app</string>
<key>aps-environment</key>
<string>production</string>
<key>beta-reports-active</key>
<true/>
<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
<array>
<string>000000000.com.myapp.app</string>

</array>

]]>

</Entitlements>

    <requestedDisplayResolution>standard</requestedDisplayResolution>

</iPhone>



  <iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
  <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
  <array>
    <string>1</string>
    <string>2</string>
  </array>
]]></InfoAdditions>

  </iPhone>


  <extensions>
    <extensionID>com.milkmangames.extensions.EasyPush</extensionID>
  </extensions>

</application>
```